# error in sscanf while scanning char[] and int

Tags: c++

I have a sample program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    string line;
    cin >> line;
    char s1[12];
    char s2[12];
    int a1 ,a2;
    sscanf((char*)line.c_str(), "%s %s %d %d", s1 ,s2 , &a1 , &a2);
    cout << s1 << endl;
    cout << s2 << endl;
    cout << a1 << endl;
    cout << a2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Input from command line:
Hello World 23 456

The output of the program is not coming as expected:

**Output:**
Hello 
����"+ 
-74572855 
11042

can anyone please tell me where is the problem ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because:

```
cin >> line;
```

Reads a single **word**, not a sentence!

Change it to:

```
getline(cin, line);
```

And everything will work!

---

**Note:** As other answers pointed out, you should be more careful when using string parsing methods

- Always check the return value of string parsing methods (in this case sscanf) before using the parsed values. In this case, you would have noticed that the return value is 1, and that only the first string was set.
- Always protect against memory corruption by explicitly specifying the maximal length of the string you allow by using `%<length>s`, in this case, `%11s` since `s1` and `s2` are 12 chars long and `sscanf` appends a null terminator.

Comment: Also, `%s` should use length limiting to avoid buffer overflows

Comment: @M.M, Added a comment for that as well